# How to set dynamic HTML data in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a response data in form of HTML from backend (Laravel) which I need to display on Angular Component.

component.ts file:

```
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private myService: MyDemoService
    ) { }

    public params = {
        lang: null,
        page_name: 'FAQ'
    };
    public faq = null;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getAppContent();
    }

    getAppContent() {
        this.myService.getAppContent(this.params).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.handleResponse(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }

    handleResponse(response) {
        if (response.status === 1) {
            this.faq = response.responseData.content;
        }
    }

}
```

After saving response in faq, I have data in faq as follows:

```
<div id="accordion" class="custom-accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link "
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#collapseOne"
                aria-expanded="true"
                aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Dummy Text <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-up ">&nbsp;</i>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show"
         aria-labelledby="headingOne"
         data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Accordion is working
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link "
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#collapseOne"
                aria-expanded="true"
                aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Dummy Text <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-up ">&nbsp;</i>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show"
         aria-labelledby="headingOne"
         data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Accordion is working
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I tried so far:

```
<div [innerHTML]="faq"></div>
```

The text is same what it gets from backend. But I don't why it isn't working. Accordion isn't working like it has to be.
Please help!

Comment: could you show what data is come from the backend?

Comment: Please show us how you retrieve the data and what type the data is supposed to look like. Other than that, you can display variables in angular via `{{variableName}}`.

Comment: if (response.status === 1) {  // check here , you are getting data here or not

Comment: when handleResponse called ? in Onint?

Comment: @StepUp It's same what I mentioned below this line "I have data in faq as follows:"

Comment: @PhilippMeissner by interpolating it prints raw html on my page. So that doesn't help.

Comment: @AkshaySharma I got the response data. My problem is that the data I got is exactly what I need but it doesn't functioned what it is supposed to be like an accordion.

Comment: @JadavPalak where I subscribed to a service & got a response inside that I called handleResponse

Comment: Alright, the first question solved. Your `faq`-variables is a `string`, that holds `HTML` which needs to be rendered.
Now, what exactly is not working? Does it render anything? If so, what's different to what you expect?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I got data as exactly same what I needed but somehow my css & js won't working on accordion like it supposed to be(accordion collapsing likewise)

Comment: That is most likely due to the accordion being initialized (with all its content) before you loaded the additional content into the DOM.
How do you initialize the accordion and when? Are you using an additional CSS framework for it?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner data is being stored in faq variable after getting response from API in component.ts & display it on component.html file

Comment: @PhilippMeissner Please check the question I have edited & post my component.ts code their.

Comment: It still does not answer the most important question. What are you using to initiate such an accordion? Angular Material? Bootstrap?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner It's bootstrap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Accordion example not working with Angular 4 \[innerHTML\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102210/bootstrap-accordion-example-not-working-with-angular-4-innerhtml)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner no mate.

Comment: Create a stqckblitz with your issue please, otherwise helping is quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [render2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) class and appendChild method

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984199/how-to-appendchild-dynamically-using-renderer2-in-angular-4).